# How to use Bootstrap in npm project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm

I've installed bootstrap and its dependencies, but I don't know how to include bootstrap in my index.html file. I've tried `require("bootstrap")` but it doesn't seem to be loading anything.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm-packages-in-your-projects

Comment: @berkobienb I'm specifically looking for a way to load the css into the webpage. All dependencies are already installed.

Comment: Are you using a specific Frontend framework?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Electron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in your index.html

(presuming that you have bootstrap as a dependency in your package.json. That you have ran the npm install. Verified that the css file is in the node_modules folder of your project)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```